# turning for loop into a function python

Tags: python, function, for-loop

```
user_input_1 = str(input("Enter fruit name"))
variable_count_vowel = 0
vowels = set("AEIOUaeiou")

for x in user_input_1:
        if x in vowels:
                variable_count_vowel = variable_count_vowel + 1

print("Number of vowels within fruit name",user_input_1,"=",variable_count_vowel)
```

I have been working on a task where the program counts the amount of specific vowels found within the users input and I would like to turn this `for` loop into a function.

Comment: Why don't you write `def my_function():` above the loop and indent the loop?

Answer (score 0):

As [mkrieger1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4621513/mkrieger1) suggested, you might just define the function over the for loop and then indent it:

```
def vowel_count(text, vowels="AEIOUaeiou"):
    variable_count_vowel = 0
    for x in text:
            if x in vowels:
                    variable_count_vowel += 1
    return variable_count_vowel

user_input_1 = str(input("Enter fruit name"))

print("Number of vowels within fruit name",user_input_1,"=",vowel_count(user_input_1))
```

Comment: i have tried this however it keeps returning that the vowel count is 1 no matter how many are in there

Comment: I made a typo, I corrected it now and tested it so it should work. I also removed the "set" for vowels and made it a standard string instead

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a regular expression, within a function or not:

```
import re
user_input_1 = str(input("Enter fruit name"))
print(len(re.findall(r'[AEIOUaeiou]',user_input1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One way would be to use *sum()* in conjunction with a generator like this:

```
VOWELS = set('aeiouAEIOU')

def vowel_count(s):
    return sum(1 for c in s if c in VOWELS)

print(vowel_count('abc'))
```